# ASP.NET MVC two different buttons in form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a single MVC form with two buttons, the page basically loads a record and the user has a approve or reject button

```
 <button id="btnAcceptAll" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Accept</button>
 <button id="btnRejectAll" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Reject</button>
```

Id like to keep it as a single form because I have a lot of hidden value I use as well.

Basically in the Form Post I wanna be able to distinguish which button was pressed.

My Form Post at the moment..

```
[ActionName("Index")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexPost(QcMatchViewModel model)
{
    //Save Record and Redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Check this post http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898553/mvc4-multibuttons-in-form-not-working-jqm/23969511#23969511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add name `attribute` to both buttons with the same value and then add `value` attribute.

```
<button id="btnAcceptAll" name="button" value="accept" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Accept</button>
<button id="btnRejectAll" name="button" value="reject" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Reject</button>
```

After that in your action method you need to add additional `button` parameter which will be filled with `value` attribute of button pressed.

```
[ActionName("Index")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexPost(string button, QcMatchViewModel model)
{
    //Save Record and Redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Or you can put additional `Button` property to your view model.

Check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form) post for some additional features.

Comment: This is the simplest, clearest version of solving this issue that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

on View :

```
<input type="submit" id="btnAcceptAll" name="btnAcceptAll" value"Accept" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/ >
<input type="submit" id="btnRejectAll" name="btnRejectAll" value"Reject" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/ >
```

On Controller:

```
[ActionName("Index")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexPost(FormCollection form, QcMatchViewModel model)
    {
      if(form["btnAcceptAll"]!=null)
       {
        //Accept Button Code
       }
       if(form["btnRejectAll"]!=null)
       {
        //Reject Button Code
       }
        //Save Record and Redirect
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible wayouts :

1> Set one property of that model to some value on either button click. i.e. let's say have a property named "accept" and on click of btnAcceptAll, set its value to true using javascript/jquery (Take accept as a hidden field) and on action method you can get that value.

2> Have 2 different action methods namely acceptChanges and RejectChanges and call them based on which button is clicked (Again using Jquery to set different form action on button click)

Answer (score 0):

On approach that is coming to my mind
You can have a field in your model, whose value can be filled by a hidden field
So you will be getting this value on post.

Now to fill value in this hidden field, you can intercept the button click event.

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
//fill hidden field value here
});
```

Comment: he wants only one action method and he wants to identify which button is pressed I guess you are not justifying his question

Comment: @Neel i didn't suggested two have to action method, the property in model will just have the action performed.